# How to get geoloation of flickr images?

Tags: jquery, flickr

How can I get the geolocation (lat and long) information

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=10&nojsoncallback=1&format=json&tags=flower&api_key=00af42177056c5b71bda9bd49938c1

I want it to output the geoloaction of the images where available in json format

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
flickr.photos.geo.getLocation(apikey, photo_id, flags)
```

will return something like:

```
<photo id="123">
    <location latitude="-17.685895" longitude="-63.36914" accuracy="6" />
</photo>
```

which  you can easily parse into a JSon string

Comment: Thanks. For reference here's the doc: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.getLocation.html